# awk expression that works on awk v4.0.2 but it does not on >= 4.2.1

Tags: bash, ubuntu, awk, centos7, alpine-linux

I have this awk command:

```
echo www.host.com |awk -F. '{$1="";OFS="." ; print $0}' | sed 's/^.//'
```

which what it does is to get the domain from the hostname:

```
host.com
```

that command works on CentOS 7 (awk v 4.0.2), but it does not work on ubuntu 19.04 (awk 4.2.1) nor alpine (gawk 5.0.1), the output is:

```
host com
```

How could I fix that awk expression so it works in recent awk versions ?

Comment: Try setting `OFS` before setting `$1` to empty.

Comment: you can cut instead. `echo www.host.com | cut -d'.' -f2,3`

Comment: Or, `echo www.host.com | grep -o '\w\w*[.]\w\w*$'`  (sorry, not directed at you @DigvijayS) or with extended regex `grep -Eo '\w+[.]\w+$'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your provided samples could you please try following. This will try to match regex from very first `.` to till last of the line and then prints after first dot to till last of line.

```
echo www.host.com | awk 'match($0,/\..*/){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)}'
```

---

---

***OP's code fix:*** In case OP wants to use his/her own tried code then following may help. There are 2 points here: 1st- We need not to use any other command along with `awk` to processing. 2nd- We need to set values of `FS` and `OFS` in `BEGIN` section which you are doing in everyline.

```
echo www.host.com | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {$1="";sub(/\./,"");print}'
```

Answer (score 4):

To get the domain, use:

```
$ echo www.host.com | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."}{print $(NF-1),$NF}'
host.com
```

Explained:

```
awk '
BEGIN {                 # before processing the data
    FS=OFS="."          # set input and output delimiters to .
}
{
    print $(NF-1),$NF   # then print the next-to-last and last fields
}'
```

It also works if you have arbitrarily long fqdns:

```
$ echo if.you.have.arbitrarily.long.fqdns.example.com |
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."}{print $(NF-1),$NF}'
example.com
```

And yeah, funny, your version really works with 4.0.2. And awk version 20121220.

**Update:**

Updated with some content checking features, see comments. Are there domains that go higher than three levels?:

```
$ echo and.with.peculiar.fqdns.like.co.uk | 
awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="."
    pecs["co\034uk"]
}
{
    print (($(NF-1),$NF) in pecs?$(NF-2) OFS:"")$(NF-1),$NF
}'
like.co.uk
```

Comment: Imagine a domain like: www.foo.co.uk

Comment: `co.uk`? Does that even brexist anymore? :D

Comment: Thanks, but this works but if the domain is composed of more than two parts it will always print the last two, for example www.host.com.co would return com.co instead of host.com.co. The next answer does correctly extract the domain on that example.

Comment: @Juancho That should show in the original question with examples and related expected output. Better luck next time.

Answer (score 3):

You got 2 very good answers on awk but I believe this should be handled with `cut` because of simplicity it offers in getting all fields starting for a known position:

```
echo 'www.host.com' | cut -d. -f2-
```

```
host.com
```

Options used are:

- `-d.`: Set delimiter as `.`
- `-f2-`: Extract all the fields starting from position 2

Comment: I did not knew about the "-" operator with cut, indeed this could be simpler. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you are observing was a bug in GNU awk which was fixed in release 4.2.1. The changlog states:

> 2014-08-12         Arnold D. Robbins
>
> OFS being set should rebuild `$0` using previous `OFS` if `$0`  needs to be
>   rebuilt. Thanks to Mike Brennan for pointing this out.
>
> - awk.h (`rebuild_record`): Declare.
> - eval.c (`set_OFS`): If not being called from `var_init()`, check  if `$0` needs rebuilding. If so, parse the record fully and rebuild it. Make `OFS` point to a separate copy of the new `OFS` for next time, since   `OFS_node->var_value->stptr` was
>     already updated at this point.
> - field.c (`rebuild_record`): Is now extern instead of static.  Use `OFS` and `OFSlen` instead of the value of `OFS_node`.

When reading the code in the OP, it states:

```
awk -F. '{$1="";OFS="." ; print $0}'
```

which, according to POSIX does the following:

1. **`-F.`:** set the field separator `FS` to represent the <dot>-character
2. read a record
3. Perform field splitting with `FS="."`
4. **`$1=""`:** redefine field 1 and rebuild record `$0` using `OFS`. At this time, `OFS` is set to be a single space. If the record `$0` was `www.foo.com` it now reads `_foo_com` (underscores represent spaces). Recompute the number of fields which are now only one as there is no `FS` available anymore.
5. **`OFS="."`:** redefine the output field separator `OFS` to be the <dot>-character. This is where the bug happens. The Gnu awk knew that a rebuild needed to happend, but did this already with the new `OFS` and not the old `OFS`.
6. **`print $0':** print the record $0 which is now`_foo_com`.

The minimal change to your program would be:

```
awk -F. '{OFS="."; $1=""; print $0}'
```

The clean change would be:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."}{$1="";print $0}'
```

The perfect change would be to replace the `awk` and `sed` by the [`cut` solution of Anubahuva](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60808973/8344060)

If you have a variable with that name in there, you could use:

```
var=www.foo.com
echo ${var#*.}
```